# How to solder a ultra small chip

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-fabrication

I need to use a PAN1780 board for a research project, but there exists no breakout board (only huge evaluation boards), so I somehow need to design my own breakout board and solder the chip on it. does anyone have an idea, how I can solder this chip on a PCB board? Or is there a company which could manufacture the PCB and also solder the chip on it?

Here are the dimensions of the board:

[PAN1780 Dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nGQj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a fairly straightforward process that any company that does reflow soldering can manage. That likely won't be the same company that manufactures the bare PCB. In any case, requests for such suppliers are explicitly off-topic here as "shopping" questions.

Generally the process would involve using a stencil to print solder paste on the pads and then passing the board + module through a reflow oven. If you design a PCB and have it made, you should request a stencil be made at the same time.

If you are in a hurry, an evaluation board would probably be more expeditious (and will likely wind up being cheaper) unless you are already pretty proficient with the PCB design process.

Comment: With 1 mm pitch it might be even possible to solder it manually, with a bit of skill.

Comment: @VladimirCravero  With big holes in the pads?

Comment: Well no :) I was thinking of hot hair, perhaps a hot plate if the PCB is big - my point was mainly that with such a large pitch, a reflow station might not be absolutely necessary for alignment.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I'm pretty sure my little batch oven would do it, but it probably would take some of the parts on the module a bit higher in temperature than ideal.